# Python: Appending to a list in a dictionary

Tags: python

SO,

Having a case of the Monday's and none of my references are helping me out.

I have a file formatted like this:

```
x1    y1    z1
x1    y2    z2
x2    y3    z3
```

I would like to make a dictionary formatted like this: {x1: [[y1, z1], [y2,z2]], x2: [y3,z3]} but I'm getting stuck on an efficient way to do this. Help?

Comment: You don't append to mappings. You append to (mutable) sequences. Don't get your collections mixed up ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to say you start with a string

```
data_str = """x1    y1    z1
              x1    y2    z2
              x2    y3    z3"""
```

Then you'll have

```
data_list = [d.split() for d in data_str.splitlines()] # [['x1', 'y1', 'z1'], ['x1', 'y2', 'z2'], ['x2', 'y3', 'z3']]
```

Then create a defaultdict

```
from collections import defaultdict
data_dict = defaultdict(list)
for data_row in data_list: # E.g., data_row = ['x1', 'y1', 'z1']
   data_dict[data_row[0]].append(data_row[1:])
print data_dict # defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'x2': [['y3', 'z3']], 'x1': [['y1', 'z1'], ['y2', 'z2']]})
```

Comment: +1 for throughout solution and getting it right in one shot ;) In Python 3, you can also use `for key, *values in data_list` (iterable unpacking, *extremely* neat).

Comment: Yeah, its a bit ugly not being able to specify the difference between the key and the value elements and nice that python3 brings allows the notation from unpacking function arguments to be used in unpacking iterables.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
def makeKeyValuePair(tokens):
    return tokens[0], tokens[1:]

print dict(makeKeyValuePair(line.rstrip().split()) for line in fileObject)
```

It creates a dictionary from key-value pairs, which in turn are extracted from each line. This of course assumes that x1, y1 and so on don't contain spaces.

As delnan pointed out, you might have the case of duplicate keys, depending on your use case. That means you'll only get values from the last line with that key. To work around this, one could use a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)

for line in fileObject:
    tokens = line.rstrip().split()
    d[tokens[0]].append(tokens[1:])
```

Comment: No, this overwrites the list if the key appears multiple times. You need a `defaultdict`.

Comment: @delnan: Unique keys is another assumption I made... I'll edit to include the `defaultdict` solution.

Comment: Well, unique keys are explicitly not the case in OP's example ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
d={}
for line in file:
    split = line.strip().split(" ")
    if not d.has_key(split[0]): d[split[0]] = []
    d[split[0]].append(split[1:])
```

Comment: This has the same issue as AndiDog's answer: It overwrites on duplicate entries.

Comment: @delnan apparently the author isnt the only one with bad case of mondays

Comment: Seemingly. Now it's a poor man's reinvention of `collections.defaultdict` ;)

Comment: @delnan did not know about that.  You learn something every day :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
result = { }
for line in lines:
    terms = line.split()
    result.setdefault(terms[0], []).append(terms[1:])
```